# In C++, what is the best way to correctly track the amount of operations X proccess uses on average, across multiple threads?

Tags: queue, benchmarking, producer-consumer, operation

I'm working on a Queue type, designed to be lockless, and support multiple producers and multiple consumers. But I have no idea how to track how many operations an enqueue/dequeue takes on average across multiple threads. I don't even know how to find out how many operations, say a function, takes to run.

When I'm looking up the issue, I find things related to how to time something using chrono, which I'm already doing.

Any help would be awesome, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

On recent x86 CPUs like Intel Skylake, there's a perf event for `mem_inst_retired.lock_loads` that you could measure with `perf stat`.  That would tell you how many atomic-RMW instructions like `lock cmpxchg` had executed, although it wouldn't tell you how many iterations a loop spin-waited retrying read-only and running `pause` instructions.

(Caveat: I haven't tried that perf event; can't confirm that it does what I expect.)

This can't distinguish the source of atomic RMWs, so you'd want to write a test harness that doesn't use many others.  But that might mean you're not doing real work between queue ops, meaning you're testing an artificially high contention case...

If you're on a different architecture or micro-architecture, perhaps there'd be something equivalent.

It also may or may not be practical for you depending on what language.  (e.g. C++ with std::atomic on x86-64 Linux is what I have in mind; something like Java probably has the JVM using atomic RMW ops in the same threads.)

---

**If you want to also/instead count *successful* queue operations**, best bet is to add instrumentation, like having each thread increment a thread-local counter on each op.  And during shutdown, add that thread-local count to a global shared total, with locking or atomics.

(Or atomic_fetch_add `mo_relaxed` to increment a shared counter all the time, but that would increase contention unless you can do it when already doing something to another shared queue variable in the same cache line, like a write-index or read-index.)  If your queue uses sequence numbers in each bucket, you might already have a counter of successful enqueue built-in.

Anyway, given a count of actual queue ops from real use of your codebase, you can divide asm atomic RMW "work" by useful progress.

**This is just off the top of my head, totally untested and may or may not be a useful metric.**